# Request Error when requesting a WCF RESTful service from Android 2.2 phone

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, json, rest

I wanted to create a method in Android that could communicate with a WCF RESTful service by giving it a string parameter.

However, whenever I make the request all I get in return is a "Request Error" error. I've tried calling the service via Fiddler, without giving it any parameters, and it works just fine.

What am I doing here, and how can I fix it?

Thanks for your time!

Here's the code for the Java method:

```
private void addNewSighting() throws Exception
{
    String URL = "http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/wcf/SightingServiceRest.svc/json/SaveNewSightingRest";

    AlertDialog popup;

    SightingWrapper sighting = new SightingWrapper();

    String xml = createXML(sighting);

    try{

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);

            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("sighting", "holi");

        StringEntity sen = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());  
        sen.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

        request.setEntity(sen);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];

            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            String responseString = new String(buffer);

            String holi = responseString;

        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {           

    }

}
```

Here's the contract for the method I want to call, which is located in the SightingServiceRest service and only returns the string "IT'S ALIVE!!":

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SaveNewSightingRest", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SaveNewSightingRest(string sighting);
```

Here's the webconfig for the WCF project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="LiveAndesWCF" connectionString="data source=tcp:sql2k802.discountasp.net;Initial Catalog=SQL2008_832326_liveandes;User ID=randomUser;Password=randomPass; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LiveAndes" connectionString="data source=tcp:sql2k802.discountasp.net;Initial Catalog=SQL2008_832326_liveandes;User ID=randomUser;Password=randomPass; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LiveAndes" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Local-->
    <!--
    <add key="mainPathDeployWCF" value="http://localhost:61642/"/>
    <add key="mainMachPathDeployWCF" value="\LiveAndesWCF\bin"/>
    -->
    <!-- Deploy -->

    <add key="mainPathDeployWCF" value="http://liveandesor.web711.discountasp.net/"/>
    <add key="mainMachPathDeployWCF" value="e:\web\liveandesor\htdocs"/>


    <!--<add key="mainMachPath" value="C:\Users\Rul\Documents\Universidad\2011'1\Taller de Especialidad\svn\Desarrollo\WEB\LiveAndesMVC\LiveAndesMVC"/>-->
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.SightingService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingService"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingService"/>
      </service>
      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.UserService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.IUserService"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="LiveAndesWCF.IUserService"/>
      </service>
      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.UserServiceRest" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.IUserServiceRest"/>
      </service>
      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.SightingServiceRest" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingServiceRest"/>
      </service>
      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.TestService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ITestService"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="LiveAndesWCF.ITestService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="76384000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="76384000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          <!--<webHttp/>-->
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />          
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's something new that showed up, the server error 
        <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'sighting' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix `JSON:` is not correct. You hardly used it in your test with Fiddler.

Replace that line with:

```
StringEntity sen = new StringEntity(json.toString());
```